# Regex for recognizing space in file name

Tags: php

I want to use regex to recognize space in the .pdf file name

So far i have been able to recognize src link to the file but it does not recognize the spaces in file name.

```
   <?php
   echo "<h1>Reading content from ITM website!</h1>";
   $ch = curl_init("http://domain.edu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=375&alias=lms");
   $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $my_file="example_homepage.txt";
   $handle = fopen($my_file, 'rb');
   $data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));

   $contents = strstr(file_get_contents('example_homepage.txt'), 'More quick links');
   $new_content = str_replace('<a href="', '<a href="http://www.domain.edu', $contents);
   $regex = '@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';
   $text = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $new_content);
   //echo $new_content;
   echo $text;
   fclose($fp);
   ?>
```

Current Output:

```
http://www.domain.edu/academiccalendar/Notice for final practical.pdf" target="_blank">Title
```

In this "Notice for final practical.pdf" does not appear as URL and just appears as text.

Comment: Sorry it is not my own file. I am fetching these links to the pdf files from another website.

Comment: Let me get you string you want to fetch links with PGF from another sites ???? If so how are you loading the file contents ???

Comment: Um i guess i just solved it myself :/

   `$regex = '@((https?://)?([-\w ]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w /_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';`

Comment: still looks like over kill to me  ... that is why i asked how you are loading the content ..... they are simpler ways to do that

Comment: I just need the links to be echo'd. Nothing else. I don't want any of its contents or anything. Just the links. These pdf files are on a different website.

Comment: PProbably too simple buth anyway (https?:\/\/)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(\/.*\.pdf)

Comment: @elrado Sorry but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you should not use regex for screen scraping. It's slow and eventually it will break. Instead, use a DOM parser or simply [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php 
//curl bit
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://itmindia.edu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=375&alias=lms");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$site = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);



$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($site);

$ret=array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $links) {
    //Is pdf
    if(substr($links->getAttribute('href'),-3) == 'pdf'){
        //Assign
        $url   = $links->getAttribute('href');
        $title = trim($links->nodeValue);
        $ret[]=array('url'=>'http://itmindia.edu'.$url,
                     'title'=>(empty($title)?basename($url):$title));
    }
}

print_r($ret);
/* Result
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://itmindia.edu/images/ITM/pdf/ITMU bro june.pdf
            [title] => ITMU Brochure
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://itmindia.edu/images/ITM/pdf/Report_2012_LR.pdf
            [title] => Annual Report to UGC July 2012
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://itmindia.edu/admission2012/PhDwinter/Ph. D. application form 2012-13 for dec 2012 admission.pdf
            [title] => Application Form
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://itmindia.edu/admission2012/PhDwinter/UF_Application_Form.pdf
            [title] => University Fellowship Form
        )
        ...
        ...
*/

//Then to output
foreach($ret as $v){
    echo '<a href="'.$v['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$v['title'].'</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but i just now updated my code. Can you please take a look at it once again and tell me what changes can i make in it?

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much what i wanted! :)

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way to recognize the string "More Quick Links" and only printing URLs after this string using your method?
Like in my code I am using 
 `$contents = strstr(file_get_contents('example_homepage.txt'), 'More quick links');` 
to check for that string. Wherever in the text file it finds that particular string, it starts printing the rest of the content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
echo "<h1>Reading content from ITM website!</h1>";
$ch = curl_init("http://itmindia.edu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=58&Itemid=375&alias=lms");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
foreach ( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $links ) {
    if (pathinfo($links->getAttribute('href'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "pdf") {
        printf("<a href=\"http://itmindia.edu/%s\">%s</a><br />", $links->getAttribute('href'), $links->nodeValue);
    }
}
```